# Log exceptions thrown by WCF service constructor?

Tags: c#, wcf

Is there any way to capture and log exceptions thrown from a WCF service's constructor?

Creating a custom `IEndpointBehavior` with a custom `IErrorHandler` seems to catch all exceptions *except* those thrown during service construction. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

I can see from the HTTP response that this situation eventually generates a `System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException`, but it would be helpful if I could log out the details from the original exception.

Comment: Why would exceptions occur in the constructor?  What are you doing in the constructor?

Comment: @KirkWoll I don't know. That's why I want to log them.

Comment: I ask because I don't include any behavior in my constructors.  Thus for me it's impossible for an exception to be thrown.  I'm surprised you have behavior in your constructors.   Also, `ServiceActivationException` is usually due to a configuration error.  In other words, it means your setup is broken and generally not something worth logging.

Comment: @KirkWoll In this specific case I happen to have a hunch. One constructor is reading service configuration data from a file. I think the file system permissions on one particular server is preventing that. But I'd like to find a general solution so I don't have to just guess when something goes wrong and I don't happen to have a debugger attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use WCF tracing

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

You can turn it on in the service configuration so no need to instrument your code.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a class to log the exception, initialize it in the constructor and call it when an exception is caught. Below is a very simple example:

```
public class MyWcfService : IMyWcfService
{
    private readonly IExceptionLogger_ exceptionLogger;

    public MyWcfService()
    {
        // Initialize dependencies
        _exceptionLogger = new ExceptionLogger();

        try
        {           
            // Code here that throws an exception
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _exceptionLogger.LogException(ex);
        }

    } // end constructor

    // Other methods here

} // end class
```